# minecraft 1.8 mob creation

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm new to Minecraft modding but I'm very well versed at programming. I'm having a hard time working out how to make a custom mob and add it to mc with the rest of the mobs does anyone have any idea how to do this in 1.8?

Comment: What have you tried thus far? We'd love to help , but we want to see some efforts 1st!!

Answer (score 0):

A broad answer for a broad question, hope it helps refine your question.

1. Get access to MC source code.
2. Copy a mob class similar to something you'd like to make and tweak it (or start from scratch if you're brave).
3. Make sure MC generates your mob class.